# InDesign: How to align text on inside panel of trifold brochure?

Tags: adobe-indesign, typography, alignment

I know how to do it technically, but I am wondering aesthetically if the inside right panel of a trifold brochure should have the text right aligned so it goes with the edge of the page, or if I should leave it left aligned so it goes with the rest of my brochure.

It may be a matter of preference but I'd like to get feedback.

Comment: So there are adjacent panels, and on the left panel there is left the line text?, And on the adjacent right panel you want to know if it should also be left justified?. Can you fall justify all of them?

Comment: I'd recommend: never right-align text, ever. Unless it's RTL like Arabic.

Comment: There's no "correct" answer here. It all depends upon the design and the designer's preference. I disagree with "never use right-aligned text" wholeheartedly. It works exceptionally well for some designs and can be a wonderful aesthetic solution to a layout problem.

Comment: The question does not mention anything about justification.

Comment: "should have the text right aligned"

Comment: Right aligned does not mean justified. What am i missing? :)

Comment: @Lucian just different uses... "right Justified" would be the same as "right aligned". "Justified", while commonly used by itself in place of "force justification" - meaning both left and right sides aligned -  merely means to align.

Comment: This page gives a good orientation about alignment options and how to assess them: http://thinkingwithtype.com/text/#alignment

Answer (score 1):

Tempted to say 'left aligned', as right aligned text is generally harder to follow in non-arabic languages. Simply aligning text to a margin just because it is a margin does not make sense. The better practice is to align your text in relation to the other design elements on the page (photos, icons, background if any, graphic elements, etc).

Sometimes the actual content can lead to using a right flowing text box, but we don't know if that's the case here. It depends on your design, font sizes, is it a headline or body text, and how much text are you actually working with?

Not having seen your actual design, i could only recommend the generally 'usual', or most likely, solution: left aligned.